# Divide subplots onto multiple screens

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I want to plot some data from a csv file using dataframe.

My code currently displays 266=14*19 separate subplots. Currently, it is coded to display all 266 subplots on one screen and each is small and difficult to read.

I tried to use a 1x1 plot

```
#fig, cx=plt.subplots(1,1, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(18,12))
```

Main code:

```
fig, cx=plt.subplots(14,19, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(18,12))
#fig, cx=plt.subplots(1,1, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(18,12))

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

cx = cx.ravel()

for i in range(0,len(Bond)):
    cx[i].plot(VelLog[Bond[i]], color='b')
    cx[i].set_xlabel('Time (ms)')
    cx[i].set_ylabel('Velocity (m/s)')
    cx[i].set_ylim(-250,150)
    cx[i].set_title(Bond[i])

plt.savefig('Velocity.png', dpi=120)
plt.show()
##################################
Error message when I un-comment Line 1
cx[i].plot(VelLog[Bond[i]], color='b')
IndexError: index 209 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 209
```

How can I only display a few subplots on a screen at a time to increase readability?

Like 5x5 + 5x5 + 5x5 + 5x5 + 5x5,+ 5x5 + 5x5 + 5x5 + 5x5 + 5x5 + 4x4 = 266

11 different screens.

Is there a way to add a chart filter as an alternative?

Here is my updated code with your suggestions. It now creates 11 figures. I was able to plot all 266 graphs but each graph looks the same

```
Nrows, Ncols = 14, 19
Nplots = Nrows*Ncols

nrows, ncols = 5, 5
naxes = nrows*ncols

nfigures = Nplots//naxes

count = 0
figures = []

for fignum in range(nfigures+1):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols,  sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(18,12))
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
    #axes = axes.ravel()
    figures.append(fig)
    axes = axes.flat
    for ax in axes:
        #print(count)
        if count<Nplots:
            for i in range(0,len(Bond)):
                cvs_row, cvs_col = divmod(count, Ncols)
                cvs_row, cvs_col = cvs_row+1, cvs_col+1
                ax.plot(VelLog[Bond[i]], color='b', label='%d,%d'%(cvs_row, cvs_col))
                ax.set_xlabel('Time (ms)')
                ax.set_ylabel('Velocity (m/s)')
                ax.set_ylim(-250,150)
                ax.set_title(Bond[i])
            count = count+1

plt.savefig('Velocity.png', dpi=120)
plt.show()
```

Here is the result for one figure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NiFX.png)

Comment: have you tried plotting them on different figure objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I plot the same function 14*19 times, but you can get an idea

We have two problems, keeping track of what we are plotting and
delaying the actual plotting until we are finished with all of them.

The first issue is solved here using a global counter and the `divmod`
builtin, the second storing all the figures in a list and calling
`plt.show()` only at the very end of the plotting phase.

To show what I mean with "keeping track" I have added a label and a
legend to each individual subplot.

To keep things reasonable I don't check if the last figure is empty
and also I don't check is some subplots of the last figures are empty,
but remember that you can remove some subplots from a figure if you
want a clean last figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 31)
y = np.sin(x)

Nrows, Ncols = 14, 19
Nplots = Nrows*Ncols

nrows, ncols = 5, 5
naxes = nrows*ncols

nfigures = Nplots//naxes

count = 0
figures = []

for fignum in range(nfigures+1):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)
    figures.append(fig)
    axes = axes.flat
    for ax in axes:
        print(count)
        if count<Nplots:
            cvs_row, cvs_col = divmod(count, Ncols)
            cvs_row, cvs_col = cvs_row+1, cvs_col+1
            ax.plot(x, y, label='%d,%d'%(cvs_row, cvs_col))
            ax.legend()
            count = count+1

plt.show()
```

Here I show just the last figure, to show what I mean with "empty
subplots"...

[image]

Comment: How come all the graphs look the same?

Comment: ¿ Have you read the first statement of my answer, i.e., _"Here I plot the **same** function 14×19 times, but you can get an idea"_ ?

Comment: To rephrase, I figured adding Vel[Bond[i]] would plot all 266 graphs.

Comment: Figured it out. I had 'i' instead of 'count'. Thanks again.